# How to get center point of radius in UIBezierPath arc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpoint

I have and objective c application. In a ViewController I have a UIView, and into this view I draw a circle with UIBezierPath with this code:

```
CAShapeLayer* clockWiseLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        clockWiseLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint
                                                              radius:radius
                                                          startAngle:startAngle
                                                            endAngle:endAngle
                                                           clockwise:YES].CGPath;
```

Then I want know what is the center of point into portion or the center of radius to the center of a part's arc like this:

[image]

How can I get this point? If I know the end, start of angle, the radius size what is the value of the point and how can I calculate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is just some basic trigonometry.

First get the angle of the center of the arc:

```
normalEnd = endAngle < startAngle ? endAngle + 2 * pi : endAngle
centerAngle = startAngle + (normalEnd - startAngle) / 2
```

Then calculate the x and y coordinate of the center of the arc relative to the center point:

```
arcCenterX = centerPoint.x + cos(centerAngle) * radius
arcCenterY = centerPoint.y + sin(centerAngle) * radius
```

Now you have the end points of a line segment and you want the center of that line segment:

```
desiredPointX = (centerPoint.x + arcCenterX) / 2
desiredPointY = (centerPoint.y + arcCenterY) / 2
```

Comment: if i am not mistaking  @user3386109 if you apply `+` then you will get upper bound of circle if you apply `-` then you will get bottom  point. both cases you will get centre point for sure.  see this image https://www.google.co.in/search?q=pi+value+ios+circle+image&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=nuzzAGmdJ7QixM%253A%252C6WAZBvKV-VL6oM%252C_&usg=__SVo5fFfJs5fjvYAU9PCD9luzZWg%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij_ILm7LjZAhUIX5QKHasDBhUQ9QEIOjAI#imgrc=nuzzAGmdJ7QixM:

Comment: @user3386109 It was wrong. I just made an update that should be correct now.

Comment: @rmaddy LOL forgot to divide

Comment: @user3386109 OK, I think I finally got it. I need to normalize the end angle so it is greater than the start angle. See the update.